# Spark: How to run PCA parallelized? Only one thread used

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, pca, apache-spark, pyspark

I use pySpark and set my configuration like following:

```py
spark = (SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]")
        .config("spark.driver.memory", "20g")
        .config("spark.executor.memory", "10g")
        .config("spark.driver.cores", "30")
        .config("spark.num.executors", "8")
        .config("spark.executor.cores", "4")
        .getOrCreate())
sc = spark.sparkContext
```

If I then run PCA:

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import PCA

pca = PCA(k=50, inputCol="features", outputCol="pcaFeatures")
model = pca.fit(train)
```

Only one thread is active and therefore the computation takes a long time.

**How can I parallelize PCA in Spark?**

I run on a local machine and did not configure a cluster in the configs.

Also I did not install the recommended ml packages, since the warning

```
WARN LAPACK: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemLAPACK
```

appears.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MLlib Linear Algebra Acceleration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-linalg-guide.html) documentation, LAPACK and related libraries need to be installed and configured corrected to get the full speed-up of Spark.

Additionally, the documentation mentions that sometimes there might not be a speed-up. That could be a result in your case because of running on a local machine compared to running on a cluster.